# Load-balancing one VPN-connection over multiple WANs

Tags: tcp, wan, tunnel, hardware, load-balancing

My internet connection will be provided by 4 different WANs (each 250 Mbit down, 100 Mbit up), which should be load-balanced to one 1 Gbit connection (full duplex, most likely ethernet (should be sufficient?))

All of our network-traffic should be tunneled through a VPN-connection.

(It's possible that in the future the speed of a single WAN could be increased even further or that the number of WANs increases. This is not our main attraction, but more a side-note.)

- My question is which hardware setting would be recommended here?
- Is it possible to first load balance all our WANs to one line and
  afterwards let another router handler the VPN-connection?
- Would it still work that this single TCP-connection (the VPN-connection) is
  load-balanced through all WANs, what is the requirement for that to
  be the case?

We thought that with load-balancing a single TCP connection will always be sent over the same WAN, but probably that's not the case?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put: that won't work. You can't terminate a single VPN connection on multiple public IP addresses.

But there's an alternative - create a VPN link for each of the WAN connections and load balance between those. Most business-grade routers should be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! What a pity, that's what we thought. By chance, do you have any hardware-recommendations for that?

Comment: Sorry, product recommendations are explicitly off-topic here. You need to look for a router with enough beef for the VPN throughput you're aiming at.